# single flexible column within a row

Tags: html, css

Few requirements I have to achieve:

1. the title (darker grey part) must be one line no matter what, add dot dot to the end
2. the darker grey part must be flexible, because the lighter grey part have to show full text and one line.

   ```
   <div width="100%">
       <div class="left">flexible, assume this is a title</div>
       <div class="right">must remain one line no matter what</div>
   </div>

   .left{
       background:grey;
       width:50%;
       float:left;
    }
   .right{
       background:lightgrey;
       width:50%;
       float:right; 
   }
   ```

The challenge of my case is that no fixed width can be used, do I need js to do some calculation?

Comment: @AlyssaGono means the right column cannot be squeeze until 2 line or hidden, it must be shown in full, contradicted to the left column, where the width depends on the width of the right.

Comment: i suggest you use calc() function in css, to calculate your .left width.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc/

Comment: All you have to do is store your .right width at the moment, and substract it to 100%. (.left(width) = 100% - .right(width)). Anyways, it was just a formula.

Answer (score 1):

Add these styles to your .left class

```
 overflow: hidden;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
 white-space: nowrap;
```

These will prevent wrapping and show the ... style if the text is too long.

Comment: I know this but what about the 2nd problem?

Comment: it isn't clear to me what you want for your second part. With a flexible layout, you either have to allow the text to wrap (more than one line) or do the same as I have suggested for the first box. Please can you clarify what you want to happen?

Comment: the right column cannot be squeeze until 2 line or hidden, it must be shown in full, contradicted to the left column, where the width depends on the width of the right